# Can we use Node.Js for server background processing?

Tags: node.js

Is node.js recommended for background tasks such as handling end of the day data processing, sending emails, push notifications etc as a server side service. Or can we rely on good old Java or .net services to handle this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You *can* do just about anything with just about anything. What *specifically* are you asking?

Comment: Yes, you can schedule the background Node processes with some Cron extension. Can be either something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron or standard server scheduler

Comment: @DaveNewton Tasks like sending account expiry emails, locking out accounts if they expire, send push notifications. etc.

Comment: SO isn't a place for tech recommendations or broad, general questions. There's no particular reason to choose or not choose NodeJS for what you've listed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Node works well for background processing.